# How to measure "controversialness" of a document given upvotes and downvotes

Tags: metric

Say that I had upvotes and downvotes for a document. I'm trying to come up with a good "controversialness" measure from this. When **both** upvotes and downvotes are large, then this measure should be large.

This is my very naive attempt at doing this:

> Agreement = Upvotes/(Upvotes + Downvotes)
>
> Disagreement = Downvotes/(Downvotes + Upvotes)
>
> Controversialness = ABS(Agreement - Disagreement)

Does anyone have an idea on how I could measure the controversialness of a post?

Comment: If you have this information as a time series, e.g., votes per week or month, then the variability and diversity of the sentiments over time could form a metric for "controversy." There are many metrics for *diversity*, as a google search will show you. One good one is the coefficient of variation defined as the std deviation of the sentiments divided by their mean.

Comment: In addition to DJonhson's notes on variability, a good indicator of controversy is seeing a bimodal distribution, with peaks at "agreement" and "disagreement" having similar heights.

Comment: This link is to a discussion on linguistic "weirdness," a highly relevant topic area... http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=5006

Comment: I'm missing something. If you had a billion upvotes and a billion downvotes, your Agreement and Disagreement would both be 1/2, and your controversialness would be zero. I'm pretty sure that's not what you intended?

Comment: Yeah - I couldn't think how to handle that.